# Zend Form Element Label "for" Attribute

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I subclass `Zend_Form` to allow re-use as I describe in [my other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440222/zend-forms-element-id-modification-to-allow-re-use).  It's working very well, except for one issue that I found.  In my view script I use this code to render the label for fields:

```
echo $this->formLabel($this->element->getFullyQualifiedName(),
        $this->element->getLabel());
```

The rendered label has the original element id as the value in the `for` attribute rather than the new, suffixed, element id.  Is there a bug in the Zend code, am I missing a step or doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Can you show how exactly and in which method (!) you've implemented new, suffixed id?

Comment: If you visit the other question that I linked to, you'll see the code.  I added a function for setting the suffix, and have overridden the `render()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is that you use `formLabel` view helper independently. As a result, the helper is not aware of any attributes that you specified for your input text field. So, you should provide these attributes to the `formLabel`. For example you could do the following:

```
echo $this->formLabel(
        $this->element->getFullyQualifiedName(),
        $this->element->getLabel(),
        $this->element->getAttribs() 
);
```

The above code should produce `for` tag that matches your input elements id. Otherwise, the `for` tag will be set to the elements name.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a third argument for the `formLabel` view helper.  I will try that.  Thanks!